# Wordpress get taxonomy name by term id

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to pull taxonomy name just by using term id? Like i have a term_id and i don't know which taxonomy it belongs to and need to get the taxonomy name that it belongs too. any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

You can use get_term(): https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

```
$term = get_term( $term_id );
echo $term->taxonomy;
```

Comment: Note that this will return a "Invalid taxonomy" error if the taxonomy is not registered as "public".

Comment: If you are looking for the display name use `$term->name`

Answer (score 2):

to get the labels of a taxonomy by one of its term ids, you would need to first get the term by calling

```
$term = get_term($term_id);
```

now you have the term object and that also includes `$term->taxonomy`.
with that info you can call for the whole taxonomy

```
$taxonomy = get_taxonomy($term->taxonomy);
```

now you have the whole package and you could extract the name from that.

```
var_dump($taxonomy);

$label = $taxonomy->label;
$name = $taxonomy->labels->name;
$singular_name = $taxonomy->labels->singular_name;
```

or you could call another function, that gets you all the labels:

```
$labels = get_taxonomy_labels($taxonomy);

var_dump($labels);
echo $labels->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

**One can get taxanomy name using term id:**

In the below example group_types is the custom taxonomy in WordPress

```
$groupTypeName = get_term_by('term_taxonomy_id','group_types' , 'category');
$tax_name= $groupTypeName->name;
echo $tax_name;
```